# Setting background of a toggle button based on its state

Tags: wpf, button, background, styles, toggle

I'm trying to make the background color of a toggle button to transparent if isChecked=true or false and if the mouse is over the control. So to say, in any circumstances.

This is what I tried last:

```
<ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="48" IsChecked="{Binding DownloadImages}">
<ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DownloadImages}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Style="{StaticResource ToggleOnImage}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DownloadImages}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                       <Image Style="{StaticResource ToggleOffImage}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ToggleButton.Style>
```

Sadly it produces the following result:

[image: Only the blue bg settings works]

This shows that only the Blue background setter is working.
Images swap correctly, only the background of On state and MouseOver remains that windows style blue.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: triggers for `DownloadImages` are mutually exclusive, so one of them works every time. they have higher pririty than `IsMouseOver` trigger, because they are written after IsMouseOver. you should probably put IsMouseOver trigger last, or use MultiDataTrigger with multiple conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I had to completely rewrite the Template Property and I suggest this to everyone. Always customize the Template, even though you don't want to edit anything. Half of xaml problems can be get ridden of.
And to avoid other bunch of code errors: Always set TargetType of a ControlTemplate.

code:

```
<ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template"/>
           <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
               <Grid....>
```